# Render component when receive props ans styled it inline

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I try render component when parent receives props. But catch error:

*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.*
I use material ui, when icon props true I need to render element inside FloatingActionButton. IN case I use `<Icon />` I catch error, in case I use just Icon - it wroks, but how to apply any styles.

```
const IconButton = ({color = 'normal', icon, ...props}) =>{
    let Icon = icon
    console.log(Icon)
    return <FloatingActionButton
        disableTouchRipple
        mini
        zDepth={1}
        {...props}
        {...getStyle(color, props.disabled, props.icon)}
        >
        {!!Icon && <Icon />}
        </FloatingActionButton>
}

<IconButton color='hightligted' icon={<Add />} />
```

This variant works, but how to set style in this case to Icon :

```
{!!Icon && Icon}
```

Comment: You should post a new question considering you solved your own problem.

Comment: What is your problem? I did not understand. Try to explain in a clearer way

Comment: How to set what style?

Comment: updated description